# Copy specific characters from a pointer in c

Tags: c, pointers, char

I am having an issue trying to copy the right points from a string. Here is the loop I am using to copy characters from one pointer to another. string_ptr is declared as char **string_ptr

```
while (is_letter(**string_ptr) == 1) {
    strncpy(word, *string_ptr, i);
    *string_ptr += 1;
    i++;
}
```

string_ptr is connected to a variable that contains a sentence, lets say "The quick brown fox jumped." that is not an array. is_letter just checks if the current character is a letter or not, if true, the loop is supposed to copy that letter from the sentence into another char pointer called word (not an array either). When I run the loop this is my output...

```
word = "e "
```

Yet my output should be

```
word = "The"
```

It appears that I am skipping the first 2 characters in my sentence, how do I fix this kind of error?

Comment: show the type of `string_ptr` and what it is....

Comment: Better create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: I also recommend you [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). And read about [the standard character classification functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte#Character_classification).

Comment: A hint though: The `strncpy` function will *overwrite* whatever is in `word`. Another hint: It's not the only thing wrong with that `strncpy` call.

Comment: I increment i because I need to add '\0' at the end of word

Comment: In the question you say "string_ptr is a char". If by this you mean you've created the declaration `char  string_ptr;` then your example wouldn't compile, so clearly I must have that wrong. Did you mean `char **string_ptr;`?

Comment: Regarding that increment of `i`, while it's good you think about the terminator, the increment is *wrong*. The reason is because the first iteration you will copy `0` characters. The second iteration you will copy `1` character. The third iteration you will copy `2` characters. Etc. That's what I means by my second "hint" above. You don't need the `strncpy` call *at all* actually, just copying from (dereferenced) pointer to (dereferenced) pointer, and incrementing them.

Comment: I see what you mean about my wrong increment of i. But I don't see how I would copy without using strncpy or strcpy.

Comment: @ClaytonD: Have you considered using `strncat` instead? That would preserve whatever is in `word` already...

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem strncat makes this work as intended thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

> word = "e "
>
> Yet my output should be
>
> word = "The"

Of course it is "e" because you increment it:

```
*string_ptr += 1;
```

I suggest:

```
for (i = 0; string_ptr[0][i] != '\0'; i++) 
    word[i] = string_ptr[0][i];
word[i] = '\0';
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please add some more details to your answer to make it clearer, helpful and to avoid deletion.